# Real world terrain import into UE4

Tags: terrain, world-design

I am trying to create a basic game in Unreal Engine 4.8.1 and I wish to have it set in the Dubai, UAE but i cannot find a way that will successfully use terrain data i have obtained (NASA Shuttle RADAR 90m) to create a 1:1 scale map in unreal without creating huge world spikes. Does anyone know a method that can import the data without creating terrain spikes?

Comment: I've never used UE before, but spikes would most likely be caused due to not having enough polygons/vertexes on your terrain mesh. Adding some smarts to smooth out intense spikes might be a suitable solution, or adding more polygons/vertexes. Another thing you could do is prioritize vertex density around small areas that have large variations in height to try and handle these spikes